# Android Kotlin: Bottom Sheet Dialog keyboard overlap the button

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, bottom-sheet

How to keyboard under button?

[image]

> Fragment

```
class ForgotPasswordBtmSheet : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

private lateinit var binding: ForgotPasswordBtmSheetBinding

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    // Binding
    binding = ForgotPasswordBtmSheetBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    val view = binding.root


    // Dialog
    dialog?.setOnShowListener {
        val mDialog = it as BottomSheetDialog
        val bottomSheetInner = mDialog.findViewById<View>(R.id.design_bottom_sheet)
        if (bottomSheetInner != null) {
            BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheetInner).state =
                BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
        }
    }


    return view
}
```

> Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/btm_sheet_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="16dp"
app:behavior_hideable="true"
app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"
tools:context=".auth.ForgotPasswordBtmSheet">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:background="@color/androidBG"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        style="@style/TextViewTheme"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/form_forgot_password"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_subject" />

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        style="@style/TextViewTheme"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/act_chg_password_remark"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_small" />


    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/edtV_email_layout"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/edt_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/edt_height"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:hint="@string/act_email">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/edtV_email"
            style="@style/EditTextTheme"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_submit"
        style="@style/ButtonTheme"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/button_block_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/app_button_submit" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add `adjustResize` flag to your activity in `AndroidManifest`. There are two main flags which are the following.

> **adjustResize**
> The activity's main window is always resized to make room for the soft keyboard on screen.

> **adjustPan**
> The activity's main window is not resized to make room for the soft keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are automatically panned so that the current focus is never obscured by the keyboard and users can always see what they are typing. This is generally less desirable than resizing, because the user may need to close the soft keyboard to get at and interact with obscured parts of the window.

So I suggest you use the `adjustResize` which seems what you want. If not you might also want to experiment with `adjustPan` once.

```xml
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"> </activity>
```